# How to transform a pdf file or blob in a base64?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, base64, encode

My API in NodeJS is making a response with a pdf file, but my front-end using react cannot get this file and make 'downloadable' soo I trying to convert this in base 64. The question is, how?

I try using this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64) in this way:

```
  const bytes = await utf8.encode(bill)
  const encoded = await base64.encode(bytes)
  console.log(typeof encoded)
  console.log(typeof bytes)
```

And in this project i use [this module too](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-bill-2) and he use PDFkit to generate a billet and i am using Adonis in this project

```
    const duplicata = await Duplicata.findBy('id', params.id)
const banco = await duplicata.banco().fetch()
const empresa = await duplicata.empresa().fetch()
const cliente = await Cliente.findBy('cnpj', auth.user.cnpj)
const clienteEnderecos = await cliente.clienteEnderecos().fetch()
const endereco = await clienteEnderecos.toJSON().find(endereco => {
  if (endereco.tipo_endereco === 'COBRANCA') {
    return endereco
  }
  if (endereco.tipo_endereco === 'PRINCIPAL') {
    return endereco
  }
  if (endereco.tipo_endereco === 'ENTREGA') {
    return endereco
  }
})

empresa.bairro = empresa.bairro.trim()
cliente.nome_razao = cliente.nome_razao.trim()
cliente.sobrenome_fantasia = cliente.sobrenome_fantasia.trim()

const boleto = {
  banco: Utils.getBankModel(banco.cod_banco),
  pagador: {
    Nome: cliente.nome_razao + ' ' + cliente.sobrenome_fantasia,
    RegistroNacional: cliente.cnpj,
    Logradouro: endereco.endereco,
    Bairro: endereco.bairro,
    Uf: endereco.uf,
    Cep: endereco.cep
  },
  beneficiario: {
    dadosBancarios: {
      carteira: banco.carteira,
      agencia: banco.agencia,
      agenciaDigito: banco.digito,
      conta: banco.conta,
      contaDigito: banco.digito_conta,
      nossoNumero: duplicata.nro_documento.slice(0, -1),
      nossoNumeroDigito: duplicata.nro_documento && duplicata.nro_documento.charAt(duplicata.nro_documento.length - 1)
    },
    dadosEndereco: {
      descricao: empresa.descricao,
      endereco: empresa.endereco,
      bairro: empresa.bairro,
      cidade: empresa.cidade,
      uf: empresa.uf,
      cep: empresa.cep,
      numero: empresa.numero,
      cnpj_empresa: empresa.cnpj_empresa
    }
  },
  boleto: {
    numeroDocumento: duplicata.nro_duplicata + ' ' + duplicata.serie_duplicata,
    especieDocumento: 'DM',
    valor: parseFloat(duplicata.valor_duplicata),
    datas: {
      vencimento: moment(duplicata.vencimento_duplicata, 'mm-dd-yyyy'),
      processamento: moment(duplicata.emissao_duplicata, 'mm-dd-yyyy'),
      documentos: moment(duplicata.emissao_duplicata, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
    }
  },
  instrucao: {
    Juros: parseFloat(duplicata.juros_mora)
  }

}

const novoBoleto = Utils.gerarBoleto(boleto)
    try {
  if (!fs.existsSync((Helpers.tmpPath('boletos')))) fs.mkdirSync('./tmp/boletos')
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream(Helpers.tmpPath('boletos/boleto.pdf'))

  const boleto = await new Gerador.boleto.Gerador(novoBoleto).gerarPDF({
    creditos: '',
    stream: stream
  })
  boleto.end()

  const bytes = await utf8.encode(boleto)
  const encoded = await base64.encode(bytes)
  console.log(encoded)
  console.log(bytes)

  response.type('pdf')
  response.implicitEnd = false

  boleto.pipe(response.response)
```

mostly variables in this package is in Portuguese

but my console I cannot get any answer, just an empty string, just in the variable encoded but only I don't encode with a utf8 encoder, but the response doesn't is what I expect (a base64 answer).

I don't know how to show my code in a way useful soo I open to any suggestions or what informations I need to show to better get a solution, tks :D

Comment: I think your program (at least the snipet above) is already working fine, just remove the `typeof` from `console.log(typeof encoded)` and you get your base64 encoded result.

Comment: unfortunately, the result of this console.log(encoded) its just a empty string, don't show anything @jps

Comment: we only see these 4 lines, which is certainly not the complete program, and these 4 lines seem to be correct (beside the `typeof`). So please show a minimal, complete example that shows a reproducable error (something that I can just copy to my pc and run it directly without the need to edit anything)

Comment: I will eddit and add some more informations, if it is not enough, tell me what more i can add

Comment: just enough to make a runnable programm! To make it runnable, I had to add two `require`lines for base64 and utf8 and give `bill` a value. But then it worked for me.

Comment: I make some changes, i think maybe this is enough? If not, tell me what do you need @jps